# Updating one row with different conditions in one query

Tags: mysql

I try to execute these three queries at the same time, but I get to execute each query only separately.

```
UPDATE post SET category=CONCAT(category,',2') WHERE id = 1 AND category LIKE '%5%' AND category LIKE '%1%'; 
UPDATE post SET category=CONCAT(category,',4') WHERE id = 1 AND category LIKE '%5%' AND category LIKE '%2%'; 
UPDATE post SET category=CONCAT(category,',6') WHERE id = 1 AND category LIKE '%5%' AND category LIKE '%3%';
```

I can not understand how to write a query correctly:

```
UPDATE post SET
category = CONCAT(category,',2')IF(id 1 AND category LIKE '%1%'),
category = CONCAT(category,',4')IF(id 1 AND category LIKE '%2%'),
category = CONCAT(category,',6')IF(id 1 AND category LIKE '%3%')
WHERE id 1 AND category LIKE '%5%';
```

Comment: Can you add them to a .sql file and run the file?

Comment: Does `IF` actually exist in MySQL? I mean, MySQL has some weird non-standard syntax, but I have never seen this one.

Comment: Please include the documentation where you found the `IF` clause.

Comment: Warning this also matches 11, 111, 1111 ... and 22, 222, 2222... and 55, 555, 5555... and so on or any other number with atleast one 1, 2, 3 or 5 in it.. i think you need to use `FIND_IN_SET` because it looks like you are using comma separated values in category

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: There is no question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the current task with using CASE statement

```
UPDATE post 
SET category = CASE  
  WHEN category LIKE '%1%' THEN CONCAT(category,',1')
  WHEN category LIKE '%2%' THEN CONCAT(category,',2')
  WHEN category LIKE '%3%' THEN CONCAT(category,',3')
  ELSE category
END 
WHERE id = 1 AND category LIKE '%5%'
```

But this task means that the stucture of your database is wrong and it need to normalization. You should read about the 1st normalization form

Comment: Warning this also matches 11, 111, 1111 ... and 22, 222, 2222... and so on or any other number with atleast one 1, 2, 3 in it

Comment: @Raymond Nijland, yes. You are right, because storing array of id in a text field is bad way. Here need to use 1st normalization form

Comment: "Here need to use 1st normalization form " yes i know but sometimes it's not possible to change a working application.. `FIND_IN_SET` ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set ) is a safest option MySQL has to work with non-normalizated data atleast when the string is comma separated that is.

Comment: When category contains 1,2,3 it works only with first element = 1,2,3,1 (i need 1,2,3,1,2,3)

Comment: @noobsaibot read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: As a side note, `WHEN category like %1%` in a comma delimited field should be rewritten as `WHEN concat(',', category,',') LIKE '%,1,%'` that way you avoid false positives when you get to 9,**10**,**11**,**21**

Answer (score 0):

Use Conditional Branching inside the [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```
UPDATE post 
SET category = IF(category LIKE '%1%', 
                  CONCAT(category,',2'), 
                  IF(category LIKE '%2%', 
                     CONCAT(category,',4'), 
                     IF(category LIKE '%3%', 
                        CONCAT(category,',6'), 
                        category
                       )
                    )
                 )
WHERE id = 1 
  AND category LIKE '%5%'
```

Comment: This is a situation where using the CASE statement would be a better fit since there are multiple conditions rather than a simple true false condition.

Comment: @SloanThrasher agree! Just one more way out there, other than `CASE`

Comment: Warning this also matches 11, 111, 1111 ... and 22, 222, 2222... and so on or any other number with atleast one 1, 2, 3 in it

Comment: IF vs case... IMHO case statement will always win because of readability. @RaymondNijland Indeed, check my comment in Maxim's answer.

Comment: @bradbury9 in this particular case, yes!. However I dont agree about generalizing it. `CASE` is more verbose and requires formatting; while `IF` is straightforward in case of single conditions

Comment: Another reason I dislike `IF` function: It is mysql specific a `case` would work for you if you port your code to other DBMS